# The list chromatic number of a graph is at most the product of the chromatic number and log of the number of vertices.

Tags: graph-theory, reference-request, coloring

Let $G = (V, E)$ be a graph on $n$ vertices.

Let $\text{ch}(G)$ be the **[list chromatic number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_coloring)** of $G$ and $\chi(G)$ be the chromatic number of $G$.

[This wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_coloring) article states that $\text{ch}(G) \leq \chi(G)\ln n$.

I am unable to locate a proof of this fact (the reference given on wiki also does not provide a proof).

I looked at West and Diestel and could not find a proof there too.

Can somebody supply a proof of give a reference?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second reference on Wikipedia gives a proof. It is a generalization of the more well-known proof for bipartite graphs.

Let $\chi(G) = k$; we can think of a $k$-coloring of $G$ as a partition of the vertices of $G$ into $k$ independent sets $S_1 \cup S_2 \cup \dots \cup S_k$. Suppose we have lists of $k \ln n$ colors on every vertex.

Go through the colors used in those lists; for every color, randomly pick an $i$ between $1$ and $k$, and use it on every vertex in $S_i$ that has that color on its list. The probability that a vertex is left uncolored is the probability that every time one of its $k\ln n$ colors comes up, one of the other $k-1$ sets is chosen. This probability is $(1 - \frac1k)^{k \ln n} < (e^{-1/k})^{k\ln n} = \frac1n$, so the expected number of vertices left uncolored is less than $\frac1n \cdot n = 1$. Therefore there must be an outcome with $0$ vertices left uncolored; that is, $G$ is $(k\ln n)$-choosable.

Comment: Thanks for the argument. If I understand correctly, a bound of $k \ln(\ln n)$ should also work (for large enough $n$)?

Comment: Why do you say that?

Comment: When we calculate the probability that a vertex may be left uncolored, this probability would be equal to $(1 - 1/k)^{k \ln(\ln n)}$ which is at most $(e^{-1/k})^{k\ln(\ln n)} = e^{\ln(1/\ln(n))} = 1/\ln(n)$. This number is smaller than $1$ for large enough $n$. I may be overlooking something.

Comment: We are going to multiply this probability by $n$ to find the expected number of uncolored vertices, so it must be smaller than $\frac1n$, not smaller than $1$.

Comment: Oh right. Thanks.

Comment: The bound seems asymptotically tight, at least in some cases. For example, when $n = \binom{2t-1}{t}$, the bipartite graph $K_{n,n}$ is not $t$-choosable; here we have $t \approx \log_4 n$.